# Create overlapping transparent images

Tags: unity, shaders, fragment-shader, stencil

I want to achieve this effect in the image.

To make this I don't think a single pass to a stencil buffer would be enough because stencil buffers can't mask out the actual alpha inside of the intersections.

[image]

What I have now is **this** which is relatively easy to achieve.

[image]

But what I want to do is **this**.

[image]

I think this effect can be achieved by rendering another texture that completely replaces the pixels in the middle with transparency. But here I become confused. Is it really possible to "render transparency" insted of actual color pixels and how would I even use it in this case?

Much thanks if you want to help! :)

Comment: The questions are decidedly duplicates as-is. Since you seemed to find one of the new answers helpful, I've merged it into the old question as well.